# Changing Background in Yii2

Tags: css, yii2

How can I achieve changing backgrounds in Yii2? I am new to Yii2.

Here is something similar: [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZyOPZ)

Do I need to do it via `CSS` or should i do it via any `Extensions` ?

Comment: sorry, question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view file make html structure like in your link, next you need to load css and js code. You can do it in few ways, but most simple is add it in the same view file like below:

```
<?php $cssContent = 'put css content here';
$this->registerCss($cssContent);
$jsContent = 'put your javascript content here';
$this->registerJs($jsContent);
?>
<div id="change-bg-image"></div>
<div id="change-bg-color">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via javascript, just change wrapper or document.body style.

The variable is for example there:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage
```

Happy coding.

(you can declare array of links to images and do setInterval, also you can despite of document.body use for example document.getElementById("background") )